# Using pthreads to complete work in for loop

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a 2D array I need to perform some work on. Currently, I have a single-thread design for my program and I want to move it into a multi-thread design using pthreads (OpenMP would be much easier, but that is not acceptable for this task unfortunately). Here's a sample of the code I have below with my pthread_create call within a for loop to create 4 threads. I need to subsequently run a for loop after the pthread_create loop is done. How can I run the for loop using multiple threads? Do I need to create and pass a function to pthread_create or can I simply have the for loop immediately after?

```
void main() {

    int Array[10][15];

    int numThreads = 4;

    pthread_t threadId[numThreads];

    initArray(A,20); //Initializes the array and fills with some random data

    for(i = 0; i<numThreads; i++){

        pthread_create( &threadId[i], NULL); //Normally this would take an argument for some command I want to run concurrently, however, I want to run a for loop next concurrently using pthreads.

    }

}
```

Comment: If it really needs to be *after*, then you have to `pthread_join` all of the threads first.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that you can use pthreads but not OpenMP.  Is that a true technology contraint, or an external, artificially imposed one?

Comment: @Cheatah - I need the threads to run over a for loop after my pthread_create loop, so the work in the subsequent loop would be split among the newly-created threads.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. This just sounds like an XY-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I run the for loop using multiple threads?

You can't, not in the same sense that auto-parallelization with OpenMP would do.  If you want to split loop iterations among multiple threads without OpenMP or a similar tool, then you need to implement that manually.

> Do I need to create and pass a function to pthread_create or can I simply have the for loop immediately after?

The `pthread_create()` function is not variadic.  All arguments are required.  And like any C function, `pthread_create()` is not contextual.  Its behavior is not contingent on the structure of the code around a call to it.  The thread created by a successful call to `pthread_create()` will perform the work defined by the specified function and argument to that function.  So yes, you have to create a function.

And note, again, that it is on you to define the function(s) appropriately and to pass appropriate arguments so as to implement the division of work you want.

Comment: Thank you; I suspected and was afraid this was the answer.